# Flutter doctor cannot find CHROME_EXECUTABLE in android studio even though I have set CHROME_EXECUTABLE in .bashrc

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, web, flutter-doctor

I have exported the CHROME_EXECUTABLE in my .bashrc and
I have no issues when i run flutter doctor in my terminal. See the below output

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Linux, locale en_IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

But when I run flutter doctor from the android studio via Tools->Flutter-> Flutter Doctor. I am getting error that there is not CHROME_EXECUTABLE available.
see the output below.

```
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
```

Is there some setting I have to change in andrioid studio so that i can use my chrome as
a device.
Thanks in advance.:)

Answer (score 3):

Try this;

1. Go to Settings > 'Appearance and Behavior' > 'Path Variables'
2. Click the little plus in the top right corner
3. Set CHROME_EXECUTABLE

Comment: After setting the `CHROME_EXECUTABLE` in the Path Variables and restarted the Android Studio, the `flutter doctor` in Android Studio still cannot find the Chrome / the `CHROME_EXECUTABLE` variable.

Comment: Setting variable in PATH should look like this on macOS: 
`export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`